# Replacement for dalvik.system.VMStack

Tags: java, android, api

Is there a replacement for `import dalvik.system.VMStack`?

The Android API says that it is deprecated. What I am trying to do is port someone's old project to a newer system. Is it possible there is a direct replacement to this API or can some one recommend a way to work around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that you need from it? You can get the ClassLoader from [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29). StackTrace is also available. Need anything else?